# Flatten a JSONB file - What function/query

Tags: postgresql, table, pivot, csv

In a bit of a pickle at work - I have a Jsonb which I need to flatten a file that has similar structure:

```
{
   "Manufacturers":[
      {
         "manufacturer":"Tesla",
         "address":"Deer Creek Road Palo Alto",
         "contact":"support@tesla.com"
      },
      {
         "manufacturer":"BMW",
         "address":"Petuelring 130, 80809 München",
         "contact":"support@bmw.com"
      }
   ]
```

I want this in a table format where manufacturing are column names! Something like this - [Postgres JSONB - Flatten nested objects and groupings](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/276002/postgres-jsonb-flatten-nested-objects-and-groupings)! Can't seem to understand how to get there. He has mentioned using `jsonb_to_recordset` but not sure how to get everything in a typical csv format.

Example of how I want to see the data -

[image: manufacturer |]

Comment: How do you want to show this? `name` is an array so in theory could have multiple objects, do you want that as a separate table, or to somehow correlate back to `manufacturer` in a single table?

Comment: `manufacturer` is an array as well. How do the array elements of `manufacturer` and `name` relate? What is the output you want from that example?

Comment: @Charlieface I'm trying to convert let's say Manufacturer into a CSV - ie even if I have 100 different manufacturers ie TESLA,BMW,AUDI with their information I see them in a CSV format with columns such as Manufacturer,  address, contact etc I get it initially my question is not possible. Would appreciate your help!

Comment: Please show in your question how you would like to see the information

Comment: Made the edits! Let me know if it makes sense. The code you sent is not working!

```ERROR:  column t.jsoncolumn does not exist
LINE 3: CROSS JOIN jsonb_to_recordset(t.jsonColumn->'Manufacturers')```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use `jsonb_to_recordset`, but you also need to use `->` to pull out the `manufacturer` property.

Your expected result is unclear, but it looks like you could do this:

```
SELECT j.*
FROM YourTable t
CROSS JOIN jsonb_to_recordset(t.jsonColumn->'manufacturer')
    AS j(manufacturer varchar(100), address varchar(100), contact varchar(100));
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a03e3c84706d60e0e01636b7a1a67b9e)